# Travis CI throws status code 403 when using DefinitelyTyped/tsd

Tags: https, continuous-integration, travis-ci, github-api, definitelytyped

When Building a project with *Travis CI* one of my install commands (defined in the `.travis.yml` abort due to status code 403:

```
tsd reinstall
-> running reinstall
-> an error occured!
unexpected status code: 403 on: https://api.github.com/repos/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/branches/master
Error: unexpected status code: 403 on: https://api.github.com/repos/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/branches/master
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/tsd/build/http/CacheStreamLoader.js:158:28)
    at Request.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Request.onRequestResponse (/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/tsd/node_modules/request/request.js:1156:10)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:426:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:111:23)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:317:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
[...]
The command "tsd reinstall" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

When calling the [github api url](https://api.github.com/repos/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/branches/master) from my local machine, I get a normal response. So it must be something between travis and github api.

Comment: I just got the same issue. No clue though how to fix it yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As instructed by [Blake Embrey](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/175#issuecomment-113523177), whenever using [tsd](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd) anywhere but your local machine, we should use a `.tsdrc` where we add a Github API token (or use an env var `TSD_GITHUB_TOKEN` which would be wiser for security reasons - on Travis you can [encrypt](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Encrypting-Variables-Using-a-Public-Key) the token).

Instructions on how the token is created can also be found on the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd#tsdrc) repo page, everything is explained is there.

Comment: oh nice! I'll give it a shot and return with some feedback :)

Comment: It worked a little different. I had to create a GitHub token, like explained in your second link. But the environment variable was simply set up in the settings of travis using the UI.

Comment: @waog I usually prefer the CLI, it's just a matter of preference :)